# Create dependent triggers in GCP cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-build

I need to create a dependent trigger in cloud build. Currently I have two triggers as shown in below image, both of which are created on push event to master branch in respective repos.

'app-engine-test' is triggered on pushing the code to a cloud repository whereas 'seleniumTest' is triggered on pushing code to a Git repository.

However I want to trigger 'seleniumTest' trigger once 'app-engine-test' build is completed. I could not find any such setting in GCP UI.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You *may* be able to do this by using a Pub/Sub message as the trigger for your dependent build.

When a CloudBuild build runs it publishes messages to a Pub/Sub topic `cloud-builds` - see https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications.

So if you have builds `app` and `test`, `app` would be triggered when you push to source control, and `test` triggered when a message on the `cloud-builds` topic is published.

I haven't tested this myself, but need something similar so will update this answer as I go. If it turns out you can't subscribe to the `cloud-builds` event then at the end of the `app` build you could also publish a message to your own Pub/Sub topic which you could then use to trigger the second build.

Another solution in your case might be to merge the two projects and simply run the selenium tests as a final build step once you've successfully deployed the code.

Comment: Thanks for reverting. I did look into clud-builds topic after I posted this question. But I couldn't find the cloud-builds topic in pubsub.. isnt it supposed be there. I also tried cteating a topic of my own but couldn't get to create a correct cloud function for this. Any pointers??

Comment: @adev2086 Yes, it should be there, perhaps you are lacking some permissions to be able to see it?! (shoudn't happen if you are the one building, but still, worth checking). Also, what do you mean with `couldn't get to create a correct cloud function for this`? Did you get any errors? It might be worth creating another question with the code of you functions and explaining what is not working in details.